# getchar() or putchar() keeps eating the first character of my input

Tags: c++, c, buffer, getchar, putchar

**edit: this question is solved. thank you for all answers**

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

printf("write something : \n");
int c = getchar();

while((c = getchar()) != EOF){

if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
 printf(" \n");
else
  putchar(c)
}
return 0;
}
```

everytime i run it, it works fine, but eats the first character of my input
for example when i run the program the output looks like this:

```
write something : 
this is a sentence.
his 
is
a
sentence.
```

the "t" is missing.
why is that happening and how can i fix it?

thank you for your time.

Comment: You say `int c = getchar()` which will retrieve `"t"`. Then when you say `while (c = getchar())` it will retrieve `"h"`, note that you did not even get a chance to print the character out since you called `getchar` in the while statement. Just declare `int c = 0;` and leave the `getchar()` in the while loop.

Comment: thank you for your great explanation! could you post your comment as an answer so I can choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say `int c = getchar()` which will retrieve `"t"`.
Then when you say `while (c = getchar())` it will retrieve `"h"`, note that you did not even get a chance to print the character out since you called `getchar` in the `while` statement.

To fix this, declare `int c = 0;` or `int c;`

Then when you call `getchar()` in the `while` loop you will start at the first character.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
int c = getchar()
```

you get the value of 't'. however when you call

```
while((c= getchar()) != EOF)
```

getchar is called again and the 'h' is read. you then
putchar for the first time after that. So in summary:
you call getchar twice before calling putchar. a solution to this
would be to call

```
int c = getchar();
putchar(c);
```

at the top