# taking a matrix input from the user in c

Tags: c, input

I would like to taking a 5x5 matrix input from the user with scanf in c.
for example, if the user type 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, i want to create a 2d array like this: arr[0][0] = 1 , ... arr[1][0]=6 .. etc
the input also can be with new line.

I tried this:

```
int main() {
        int arr[5][5]; eipus(arr);
        char c; int r=0; int col=0;
        while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
                if (col >= 5) { col=0; r++; }

                if (scanf("%d",&arr[r][col]) == 1) { col++; }
        }
        printArr(arr);
        return 1;
}
```

eipus() - set the array to 0. printArr - print the array.

the problem is that it always ignores the first number. for example:

```
[admin@server]$ a.out
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 5 6
7 8 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

number 1 ignored. but if there is a space before 1, it's ok.

Comment: `c=getchar()` discard reading one character.

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572964/getchar-or-putchar-keeps-eating-the-first-character-of-my-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` consumes one character. For more interesting result try giving input 
`12 3 4`

You will get the first element to be `2` then.
Use `ungetc()` to get back the previous state before reading it.

```
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
                 ungetc(c,stdin);
                if (col >= 5) { col=0; r++; }

                if (scanf("%d",&arr[r][col]) == 1) { col++; }
        }
```

By the way you need to make it `int c` as EOF is nothing but `-1`

Answer (score 0):

The very first character you enter gets scanned in variable `c` due to the line
`while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)` .

You can enter the value scanned `c` in the matrix elements throughout the loop.